# disjoint set covering with combinatorics

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory

Sorry for the vague title but I'm not familiar with the area and don't know what the right termilogy might be.

The problem I'd like to solve is: Given a collection $S$ of all the size $k$-subsets of the set $N=[1,\cdots,n]$, where $k\leq n$, find the partitions $S_i$ of $\mathcal{S}$ such that each $S_i$ covers $N$, where $S_i \bigcap S_j = \varnothing$ if $i\neq j$, and $\bigcup S_i=S$.

There are $\binom{n}{k}$ members in $S$.

An example is: $N=\{1,2,\cdots,4\}$, $k=2$, so $S=\{ \{1,2\},\{1,3\},\{1,4\},\{2,3\},\{2,4\},\{3,4\} \}$, and a partition would be

$S_1=\{ \{1,2\},\{3,4\} \}$

$S_2=\{ \{1,3\},\{3,4\} \}$

$S_3=\{ \{1,4\},\{2,3\} \}$

I see that the $k$-disjoint set cover problem is NP-complete, but this problem can be seen as a special case where the set $S$ is given as above.

I appreciate it if there are any suggestions on possible directions to solve the problem. Thank you.

Comment: What exactly do you want? A formula for the number of partitions? An algorithm to generate them?

Comment: @PeterTaylor Hi Peter, thanks for your comment. Yes I'd like an algorithm to generate these partitions if available. If generating them is NP-hard, then it'd be better if I can prove it..

Comment: It seems that you are looking for the [number of partitions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_of_a_set) of the set $N$ into subsets of size $k$ only (of course with $k | n$), is it so ?

Comment: @GCab Thanks. I think the number of partitions is $\frac{\binom{n}{k}}{\text{cardinality of each partition}}$, and the cardinality of each partition can be decided by $\frac{n}{k}$ in certain cases. I'm more concerned about generating these partitions. Thank you again.

Answer (score 2):

The algorithm is simple: to partition $N$ into subsets of size $k$ pick an arbitrary element $x \in N$. Then for each of the $\binom{|N| - 1}{k-1}$ subsets $s$ of size $k$ which contain $x$, recur on $N \setminus s$.

This also gives a simple formula for the number of ways of partitioning $kd$ elements into subsets of size $k$:
$$\prod_{i=1}^d \binom{ki-1}{k-1}
= \frac{1}{(k-1)!^d} \prod_{i=1}^d\frac{(ki-1)!}{(k(i-1))!}
= \frac{(kd-1)!}{(k-1)!^d \prod_{i=1}^{d-1} ki}
= \frac{k(kd-1)!}{k!^d (d-1)!}
$$

By Stirling's formula $n! \approx \sqrt{2\pi n} \left(\frac n e\right)^n$, this is approximately
$$\frac{e^d (kd-1)^{kd-1/2}}{(\sqrt{2\pi})^{d} k^{kd+d/2-1} (d-1)^{d-1/2}} \approx \left(\frac{e d^{(k-1)}}{\sqrt{2\pi k}}\right)^d$$
which is most certainly not polynomial in $d$, so generating all of the solutions is not in NP.

Answer (score 0):

You need $k$ to divide $n$ to make this work at all.  In that case you are breaking the $n$ items into groups of $k$.  You can do this in $\frac {n!}{(k!)^{n/k}\left(\frac nk \right)!}$ ways.  You can think of putting them in a line, which you can do in $n!$ ways and cutting the line into groups of $k$.  There are $\frac nk$ groups. Each one can be reordered in $k!$ ways, then the groups can be reordered in $\left(\frac nk \right)!$ ways, which gives the denominator.